# Stop timer in onDisconnect() event

Tags: c#, timer, signalr

I am using SignalR to grab real time updates from the database for each connected client. Each clinet has unique data so I can't have only one instance of real time updates running. I create a new object for each client. The problem is that object has System.Threading.Timer that runs callback every second to get updates from the database. Even after the clients disconnects the timer continues to run. I don't have access to object in disconnect event. How do I stop it?

```
public class DataHub : Hub
{
private readonly RealTimeData data;


public DataHub(RealTimeData rdata)
{
    data = rdata; 
}

public void Start(Int64 routerId)
{
    data.StartTimer(routerId);
}
}

 public class RealTimeData
{   
private IHubConnectionContext Clients;

public Timer timer;
private readonly int updateInterval = 1000;
private readonly object updateRecievedDataLock = new object();
private bool updateReceivedData = false;
List<Items> allItems = new List<Items>();

 public void StartTimer(Int64 routerId)
{
    this.routerId = routerId;
    timer = new Timer(GetDataForAllItems, null, updateInterval, updateInterval);       
}
  public void GetDataForAllItems(object state)
{
    if (updateReceivedData)
    {
        return;
    }
    lock (updateRecievedDataLock)
    {
        if (!updateReceivedData)
        {
            updateReceivedData = true;
            //get data from database
            allItems = Mapper.Instance.GetDataForAllItems(routerId);
            updateReceivedData = false;
            //send it to the browser for update
            BroadcastData(allItems);
        }
    }
}
}

  public override Task OnDisconnected()
  {
     //before ondisconnect is called datahub construtor is called and a new instace of real time data is made. So I can't have access to previous object here. Where do I stop the timer?
  }
```

Comment: I notice that you have only one `DataHub` constructor, and that it takes a `RealTimeData` object as a parameter. How is the Hub being instantiated? Did you register it with SignalR's dependency resolver?

Comment: yes, i added dependency resolver in startup

Comment: you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR Hubs are ephemeral. SignalR instantiates a new Hub each time it invokes a Hub method including Hub events (e.g. OnDisconnected). Since you have added your Hub to SignalR's dependency resolver, this means that SignalR will re-resolve the Hub for each connect/disconnect/invocation.

Your best bet might be to store your Timers in a static `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Timer>` keyed off of `Context.ConnectionId`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's the direction I was going in. And your answer confirmed that it's the best route.

Comment: I edited my answer to indicate that since the Dictionary is static, it should really be a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead for thread safety.

Comment: using ConcurrentDictionary, How can we stop the timer ?